# Subset data frame based on unique combination of multiple conditions

Tags: r, match, subset

I cant seem to find an answer through search to this on SO. I'm trying to select a subset of a `data.frame` based on four conditions (*lon1*, *lon2*, *lat1* and *lat2*). I have a huge dissimilarity matrix that has been vectorized and the sites (*lon1*, *lon2*, *lat1* and *lat2*) `cbind` to it. Here is an example data frame:

```
out1 <- data.frame(lon1 = sample(1:10), lon2 = sample(1:10), 
                   lat1 = sample(1:10), lat2 = sample(1:10), 
                   dissimilarity = sample(seq(0,1,.1),10))
> out1
     lon1   lon2    lat1 lat2 dissimilarity
1     2      6      4      4           0.6
2     4      2      1      3           1.0
3    10      9      2      6           0.0
4     3      1     10      8           0.5
5     9      5      9      1           0.8
6     5      7      5      9           0.9
7     1      8      6      7           0.2
8     8      3      8      5           0.7
9     7      4      3     10           0.3
10    6     10      7      2           0.1

out2 <- out1[c(2,5,6,8),]

   lon1 lon2 lat1 lat2 dissimilarity
1     4   2   1      3           1.0
2     9   5   9      1           0.8
3     5   7   5      9           0.9
4     8   3   8      5           0.7
```

I tried using `%in%` function a few times in this manner:

```
test <- out1[(out1$lon1 %in% out2$lon1) & (out1$lon2 %in% out2$lon2) & 
             (out1$lat1 %in% out2$lat1) & (out1$lat2 %in% out2$lat2), ]
```

This seems to work for the basic example I provide here. But, when I apply it to my huge data frame (with many `lat` and `lons` repeated) I get back a larger subset than the *unqiue* combinations I require. I assume because the match function in `%in%` can only match a vector. So it's matching condition1 `&` condition2 `&` condition3 `&` condition4 And thus is returning a results that gives a subset which is the same as the orginal `out1`. I want to get only the case when all four values are the same for that row. This way I'll get a subset of the data for the pairwise dissimilarities I'm interested in.

Any ideas on how to subset by row based on a unique combination of four variables would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you be more specific, I dont understand because all the 4 conditions are same in your case. Is `test` your expected output?

Comment: @e4e5f4, he wants the whole row to be matched. by doing individual comparisons and &ing them, you get all possible combinations, not necessarily the same identical elements in a row. It's not different from [**this question (to which we both answered)**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398420/subset-of-a-data-frame-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. Basically you want `duplicated` function that returns what you're expecting.

```
out1[duplicated(rbind(out2, out1)[, 1:4])[-seq_len(nrow(out2))], ]
```

---

How does it work? First we `rbind` `out2` and `out1`. Then call `duplicated` on it. The columns that are in `out2` and in `out1` will be marked as `TRUE` in `out1`. This is because the first occurrence is on `out2` and it was not duplicated there. But the second time it finds the entry, it will be in `out1` and so it'll know there has been a row exactly like this before. So, it'll mark it as duplicated. We now have all duplicated entries. From this we subset only the elements of `out1` by removing the first `n` elements where `n = nrow(out1)`. Then we subset using this *logical vector* on `out1`.

You can go through this explanation and run the code step by step to follow-up. Here's a break-down version for working out the logic.

```
tt <- rbind(out2, out1)
tt.dup <- duplicated(tt[, 1:4)] # marks all duplicate rows in out1 from 1st 4 cols
tt.dup <- tt.dup[-seq_len(nrow(out2))] # remove all out2 entries (first n)
out1[tt.dup, ] # index only TRUE/duplicated elements from out1
```

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the prompt answer. This looks really promising, but I'm still having a few issues. I'm trying to extract dissimilarities from 400 sites (dist = (400*399)/2 = 79800 rows), however I only get 38528 rows returned using the above method. Any ideas on why this might be happening? Does duplicate handle negatives? Kind regards, Skip.

Comment: Skiptoniam, if you provide a small reproducible example of where this code goes not as expected by editing your post, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Hi Arun, I've figured it out. The code wasn't working because I created the subset of dissimilarities on a different row order. Once I ordered the dissimilarities by latitude (rather than longitude) the unique combinations matched and I got 79800 rows returned. Thank you for all your help.