# R Does something like EXISTS in SQL exists in R?

Tags: r, exists, sqldf

EXISTS/NOT EXISTS are features in SQL which are incredible powerful. 
Is there a way how I can use R commands or functions to perform what I have with EXISTS in SQL? Example:

```
# Two tables
x0 <- data.frame(a=rep(1:4,2))
x1 <- data.frame(a=c(2,2,3,5))
```

I want a new indicator b which gives me 1 if the value in **x0** EXISTS in table **x1** otherwise 0.

```
# Initialize b
x0$b <- 0   

# Update b 
sqldf(c("UPDATE x0
         SET b = 1
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM x1
                       WHERE x0.a = x1.a
                      )"
        , "SELECT * FROM main.x0"
        )
      )
```

Results:

```
  a b
1 1 0
2 2 1
3 3 1
4 4 0
5 1 0
6 2 1
7 3 1
8 4 0
```

Comment: `x0$b <- (x0$a %in% x1$a) + 0L`. Much simpler than SQL.

Comment: Autsch! Yes. Put your answer as response so I can vote it. Two questions a) Why 0L and not only 0? b) `!((x0$a %in% x1$a)) + 0L` returns the logical values and not 0/1. Why?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143445/minus-operation-of-data-frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
x0$b <- (x0$a %in% x1$a) + 0L
```

Using `0L` rather than `0` is mostly me just being a bit pedantic; it ensures that everything remains as integers rather than numeric (doubles).

The reason `!(x0$a %in% x1$a) + 0L` returns the booleans, not the integers is due to operator precedence. The negation is applied last. Try moving it just one spot to the right as the first thing inside the parens: `(!x0$a %in% x1$a) + 0L`

As @Roland points out, if you find the whole `+ 0L` bit too clever to be clear, you can always just do `as.integer(x0$a %in% x1$a)`.

Comment: As a pedant I would recommend explicit coercion using `as.integer`.

Comment: @Roland Yeah, I guess adding `0L` is more like being overly clever in a slightly pedantic manner.

Comment: All joking aside, I expect that `as.integer` is also faster (although that should rarely be a concern since `+` is fast). You could also use `x0$b <- +(x0$a %in% x1$a)` if you want to code-golf.