# Join 2 dataframes together if two columns match

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have 2 dataframes:

CountryPoints

```
From.country  To.Country points
Belgium       Finland    4
Belgium       Germany    5
Malta         Italy      12
Malta         UK         1
```

and another dataframe with neighbouring/bordering countries:

```
From.country    To.Country 
    Belgium       Finland   
    Belgium       Germany   
    Malta         Italy
```

I would like to add another column in CountryPoints called neighbour (Y/N) depending if the key value pair is found in the neighbour/bordering countries dataframe. Is this somehow possible - so it is a kind of a join but the result should be a boolean column.

The result should be:

```
From.country  To.Country points  Neighbour
    Belgium       Finland    4    Y
    Belgium       Germany    5    Y
    Malta         Italy      12   Y
    Malta         UK         1    N
```

**In the question below it shows how you can merge but it doesn't show how you can add that extra boolean column**

Comment: Also, related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/test-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element

Comment: To get boolean values you could just do `df1$From.country %in% df2$From.country & df1$To.Country %in% df2$To.Country`

Comment: This will give me a true irrelevant if they are in the same row in df2

Comment: Do you need to match it row-wise? So `Belgium   Finland` in some another row would result into `N` ?

Comment: I want that if I find Belgium Finland in neighbouring/bordering countries, a Y will be written in column Neighbour in CountryPoints. Otherwise an N will be written

Comment: Would "Belgium Finland" match with "Finland Belgium"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
sortpaste <- function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "_");
df1$Neighbour <- apply(df1[, 1:2], 1, sortpaste) %in% apply(df2[, 1:2], 1, sortpaste)
#  From.country To.Country points Neighbour
#1      Belgium    Finland      4      TRUE
#2      Belgium    Germany      5      TRUE
#3        Malta      Italy     12      TRUE
#4        Malta         UK      1     FALSE
```

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "From.country  To.Country points
Belgium       Finland    4
Belgium       Germany    5
Malta         Italy      12
Malta         UK         1", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text =
    "From.country    To.Country
    Belgium       Finland
    Belgium       Germany
    Malta         Italy", header = T)
```

Answer (score 3):

Two alternative approaches:

**1) with base R:**

```
idx <- match(df1$From.country, df2$From.country, nomatch = 0) &
  match(df1$To.Country, df2$To.Country, nomatch = 0)
df1$Neighbour <- c('N','Y')[1 + idx]
```

**2) with `data.table`:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[, Neighbour := 'N'][df2, on = .(From.country, To.Country), Neighbour := 'Y'][]
```

which both give (`data.table`-output shown):

> ```
>    From.country To.Country points Neighbour
> 1:      Belgium    Finland      4         Y
> 2:      Belgium    Germany      5         Y
> 3:        Malta      Italy     12         Y
> 4:        Malta         UK      1         N
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing the idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143445):

```
df1$Neighbour  <- duplicated(rbind(df2[, 1:2], df1[, 1:2]))[ -seq_len(nrow(df2)) ]

df1
#   From.country To.Country points Neighbour
# 1      Belgium    Finland      4      TRUE
# 2      Belgium    Germany      5      TRUE
# 3        Malta      Italy     12      TRUE
# 4        Malta         UK      1     FALSE
```