# Subset a df and remove rows subsetted R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

hello I have a df called df and I have subsetted it in another df called df1. Now I'd like to remove df1 rows from df to obtain a df2 = df - df1. How I can do it on R?

```
df <- read.csv("dataframe.csv")
 
df1 <- df[(df$time <= 0.345),]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143445/minus-operation-of-data-frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```r
df2 <- df[(df$time > 0.345), ]
```

or

```r
df2 <- df[-which(df$time <= 0.345), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If for any reason you strictly have to keep the structure described, this is a possible approach:

```
df = data.frame(Sample.Name = c(12,13,14,12,13), 
                Target=c("A","B","C","A","A"), 
                Task=c("Sample","Standard","Sample","Standard","Sample"), 
                Value=c(36,34,34,35,36), 
                Mean=c(35,32,36,37,35))

df1 = df[(df$Value <= 34),]

df2 = df[do.call(paste0, df) %in% do.call(paste0, df1),]

df2
```

The result is this one:

```
  Sample.Name Target     Task Value Mean
2          13      B Standard    34   32
3          14      C   Sample    34   36
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work without even knowing the logic of first subset

```
library (dplyr) 
df2 <- setdiff(df, df1)
```

OR

```
df2 <- anti_join(df, df1)
```